# Android Fragment NullPointerException on private method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Crashlytics reports a `NullPointerException` in a `Fragment` where I call a `private method`.

This code represents my situation. Crashlytics reports a `NullPointerException` where `actionB()` is called in `actionA()`. Is the `fragment` `null`? Or why and how can this occur?

I can't reproduce this error, it occurs only for 0,5 % of my users.

```
private void actionA() {
    // Do something
    actionB();
}

private void actionB() {

    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    messageDetailHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    noMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    body.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Problem is in `// Do Something` code

Comment: @NamanGala ,Gert Dingenen :D yes. Put your code+error stacktrace

Comment: Use try catch block in both methods and log the stacktrace. You can find in which line you've got the exception

Comment: So Crashlytics can't always detect the specific line number where errors occurs? In other issues it always detects the specific line number.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your activity is not prepared yet this line:

```
getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

try to get your activity when it attaches like:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    actionA();
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```